# Looking for suitable a service in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub, anomaly-detection, azure-anomaly-detector

I'm currently looking for particular service in Azure for my side project.

I'd like to build a real-time service that gives alerts or notifications to users by detecting anomaly values from a time series data of temperatures collected over a time period of 10 months(More than 5,000,000 data exist in Azure Cloud)taken from a few devices.

I've tried [Anomaly Detector API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/anomaly-detector/), and it gives me detected values that are different from the expected values by the model, but since there is a limited input of 8,640 time series points, I can't be sure it is the model or method that I'm looking for.

My goal is to be able to input real-time temperature data through IoT sensors from few devices, like every 5 seconds, to the model, into the model that detects anomaly values based on patterns that the model would have extracted.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't build it yourself? 5,000,000 data-points isn't much - you could even probably do it all in SQL...

Answer (score 0):

There are few services in Azure which allows you to implement Anomaly Detection. Those services are:

- Azure Stream Analytics
- Azure Data Explorer
- Azure IoT Edge

To implement the Anomaly Detection in Data Explorer, you can refer Microsoft official document - [Anomaly detection and forecasting in Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/anomaly-detection)

The same can be implemented using machine learning in stream analytics service. Refer [Anomaly detection in Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-machine-learning-anomaly-detection)
.

The same ask in Microsoft Q&A helps you to integrate Azure IoT Edge and Stream Analytics for Anomaly Detection. Source [Microsoft Q&A - How to use Azure Anomaly Detection on IOT edge module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/311825/how-to-use-azure-anomaly-detection-on-iot-edge-mod.html) and Author [SandervandeVelde42](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/sandervandevelde42/)